# JavaScript escapando barra invertida \ como faço pra que isso não ocorra!

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

bom dia pessoal, estou com um problema queria uma ajuda de vcs. Algo esta fazendo com que o conteúdo passado na função escape a control barra \, eu preciso que elas não escapem pois essa função renderiza um diagrama onde todas elas são fazem parte da renderização.

```
    // escrevanatela('$$\gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,.$$');

    function escrevanatela(conteudo) {
      console.log(conteudo);
    // nesse momento meu parâmetro já mostra sem as \
      // '$$gamma(z) = int_0^infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt,.$$'
      document.getElementById("wm

d-input").value = conteudo;
  document.getElementById("wmd-button-bar").innerHTML = "";
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    Markdown.Extra.init(converter, {
      extensions: "all",
      highlighter: "prettify"
    });
    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
    editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", prettyPrint);
    editor.run();
};
```

que já souber como resolver ou até mesmo propor soluções eu agradeço D+!! abraços.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema, através da nova especificação do ECMAScript temos a String.raw com ela conseguimos passar uma cadeia de caracteres. Muito obrigado a todos que se propuseram a me ajudar :D abraços!

```
String.raw`$$\\gamma(z) = \\int_0^\\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\\,.$$`;
"$$\\gamma(z) = \\int_0^\\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\\,.$$"
```

Answer (score 3):

tente usar barras dupla para cada barra que você queira usar efetivamente.

Algo como :

```
escrevanatela('$$\\gamma(z) = \\int_0^\\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\\,.$$');

function escrevanatela(conteudo) {
  console.log(conteudo);
}
```

Abraço

Comment: complementando essa resposta, usando barras duplas, vc usa uma barra pra escapar e a outra aparece, assim, vc terá o resultado desejado.

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, mas preciso passar apenas uma \ pq estou usando um editor que converte expressões regulares para diagramas, em meu editor eu passo uma e funciona, mas diretor na função não consigo, me parece que o javascript não interpreta ela. esses eu tenho expressões que usam várias barras e se faltar um que seja quebra to o conteúdo renderizado, por isso a necessidade de utilizar essa barra única que preciso direto na função. – André Vieira 6 segs atrás editar